# What is the right way to securely deploy a private docker image on Google Cloud?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a docker image in a private docker hub repository. I have created a Google Cloud instance template for load balancing and on-demand instantiation of compute instances. What is the right way to automatically pull the repo on my newly created instances?

The only solution I can come up with is to put my docker login password in the startup script for the instance template. Is that the right approach?
GitHub has deploy keys, which allow me to put the private key in my instance for read only access, which seems like a better strategy, but I can't find anything like that for pulling a docker repo.

Comment: You are using docker hub private registry or self hosted private registry?

Comment: I am using a docker hub private registry. I think that's part of the problem. Instead I think I should be using the Google Container Registry. But how is it possible to pull from the GCR when gcloud is not installed on Google's container optimized images and the file system is noexec?